# Parameter drop down menu

Tags: python, parameters, attributes, arcgis, arcpy

Currently trying to create a Select by Attributes tool. However, I can not get my "Field Value" parameter to have a drop down menu where I can select the values within the field.

[image]

I have tried setting the dependency on the Parameters tab.

[image]

I've tried setting in within the Validation code as well.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the "updateParameter" method in the validation code. There is an in-depth ArcGIS blog article [here](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/analytics/generating-a-choice-list-from-a-field/?rmedium=blogs_esri_com&rsource=/esri/arcgis/2011/08/25/generating-a-choice-list-from-a-field/), which also links to an example script tool showcasing how to do this.

I have modified the script from the above example for your use case:

```
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()
    self.fcfield = (None, None)

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parmater
    has been changed."""
    if self.params[0].value and self.params[1].value:
      fc, col = self.params[0].value, str(self.params[1].value)
      if self.fcfield != (fc, col):
        self.fcfield = (fc, col)
        self.params[3].filter.list = [str(val) for val in
                                          set(
                                            row.getValue(col)
                                            for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc.dataSource,
                                                                          fields=col)
                                              )
                                      ]
        if self.params[3].value not in self.params[3].filter.list:
          self.params[3].value = self.params[3].filter.list[0]

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return
```

As soon as a layer and a field are selected, all available values from the datasource of the layer are displayed in the dropdown menu. Watch out: The tool parameters are addressed via indices in the script.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).